# Did I make a mistake?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, problem-solving

The question is:

> In a survey looking at reading habits at a university, it was found that 48% read magazine A, 46% read magazine B, 55% read magazine C, 18% read magazines A and B, 20% read A and C, 23% read B and C, ad 8% read all three. What percentage read atleast one of the 3 magazines.

Then what I did was state: $$ n(U) = 100 \\
n(A) = 48 \\ n(B) = 46 \\ n(C) = 55 \\ n(AB) = 18 \\ n(AC)= 20 \\ n(BC) = 23 \\ n(ABC) = 8.$$
Noting that $AB = A\cap B $

Then what I did was: $$ n(A\cup B\cup C) = n(A) + n(B) +n(C) - n(AC) - n(AB) - n(BC) + n(ABC) $$ 
when I did this I got that 96% read either A, B, or C and I was just wondering if I had made an error because it seemed a bit high when I first did it.

Comment: I think you are correct. Though the number looks high at first sight.

Comment: That’s what I get, too.

Comment: You correctly used the principle of inclusion-exclusion and the result works out. If you need more convincing try drawing a Venn Diagram and make sure everything tallies.

Comment: Why would that seem high?.  Given 48 read one 46 another and 55 the third, with that alone the number who read any magazine can be anywhere between 55  to 100 with at least 49% reading at least two.  Given that alone I would expect about 52x54x45 =12% to read none.  But given more information upping it to 96 isn't that high.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You are correct, and your approach is correct. The inclusion-exclusion principle is a method used to calculate the number of elements in the union of finite sets. For three sets, the inclusion-exclusion principle is given by

$$|A\cup B\cup C| = |A| + |B| + |C| - |A \cap C| - |A \cap B| - |B \cap C| + |A \cap B \cap C|$$

If we plug in the values you provided, then we have

$$|A\cup B\cup C| = 48+46+55-18-20-23+8 = 96$$

This is exactly your answer.

Note that the general form of the inclusion-exclusion principle is given by

$$\left|\bigcup _{i=1}^{n}A_{i}\right|={} \sum _{i=1}^{n}|A_{i}|-\sum _{1\leq i<j\leq n}|A_{i}\cap A_{j}|+\cdots {}\cdots +\sum _{1\leq i<j<k\leq n}|A_{i}\cap A_{j}\cap A_{k}|-\cdots +(-1)^{n-1}\left|A_{1}\cap \cdots \cap A_{n}\right|$$